# couchdb replication/_changes filter error

Tags: couchdb

We have production databases with 100's of thousands to millions of docs.  Filtered replication has been an issue for us.  If you tail the changes feed with a filter, *sometimes*, on timeout the result will  be `{"results":[`  and thats it.  The json object does not get closed out.

It seems that if this result is fed into the replicator, the replicator will break.

So, we do our own filtering server side, catch this botched result when it occurs, and feed the results (when we have them) into the _replicate db to let couch pick up the rest.

We use couch v1.1.1.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: you should think of filing a bug here: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CouchDB](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CouchDB). On the other hand I encourage you to update to a newer version ...

Comment: @awenkhh, we use v1.2 now.  I can't remember the issue off the top of my head, but yea it was a bug and the devs patched it up. Maybe i should close this.